# html2canvas not rendering properly (overlapping color)

Tags: html, css, angular, html2canvas, jsdoc

I am using html2canvas and jsDoc. I am rendering my current component html to pdf.
But somehow color of other component is overlapping to the current component after I download the pdf. This is Angular component.

Screenshots :

1. Screenshot from application
   [image]
2. Screenshot from pdf viewer (Sidebar visible):
   [image]

3.Screenshot from pdf viewer (Sidebar hidden):
[image]
You can see the color is overlapping from submit button till end.

Code :

```
  downloadPdf() {
    html2canvas(document.querySelector(".main-content")).then(canvas => {
      var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', [canvas.width, canvas.height]);
      var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg",1.0);
      pdf.addImage(imgData, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      pdf.save('image.pdf');
    });
  }
```

Any guess why that color is overlapping? Any other solution to render HTML to pdf?

Comment: Some guesses; Maybe it's a focus/hover state? Maybe it's related to a `print` stylesheet? It'd be helpful it you could add a minimal preproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Its related to sidebar. When sidebar is visible, color overlaps. When sidebar is hidden /removed , the color doesn't overelap.

Comment: I found out the problem, its due to width size.

Answer (score 1):

maybe my answer help someone. I resolved similar issue by adding a scale property

```
html2canvas(document.querySelector('#preview_modal'), {
    allowTaint: false,
    useCORS: true,
    scale: 2,
})
```